# Why does Scala Option.tapEach return Iterable, not Option?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

The [scaladoc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html#tapEach%5BU%5D(f:A=%3EU):C) of `Option.tapEach` states "*returns: The same logical collection as this*" just as expected for an operation named after `tap` & `foreach`. However, it does not return an `Option` but an `Iterable` backed by a `List`:

```
scala> import scala.util.chaining._

scala> Option(5).tap(_.foreach(_ => ()))
val res0: Option[Int] = Some(5)

scala> Option(5).tapEach(_ => ())
val res1: Iterable[Int] = List(5)
```

(Verified for Scala 2.13.5 and 3.0.0-RC1)

Is there a good reason to return `Iterable` instead of `Option`, or has this just been overlooked (and might be fixed eventually)?

Comment: `Option` does not have it's own implementation of `tapEach`, it is inherited from `Iterable`. Hence the result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems whether `Option` is considered a full collection is a bit of a can of worms as indicated by the discussion at [Make Option extend IterableOnce #8038](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/8038). I think the relevant [comment](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/8038#issuecomment-490799699) is

> So it can definitely be a `IterableOnce` because you can get an iterator
> of zero to one elements. But it can't be a `Iterable` because you you
> can't implement `fromSpecific(c: IterableOnce[A]): K` without throwing
> away data.

however [`tapEach`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/6c68c2825e893bb71d6dc78465ac8c6f415cbd93/src/library/scala/collection/Iterable.scala#L829) uses `fromSpecific` in its definition

```
override def tapEach[U](f: A => U): C = fromSpecific(new View.Map(this, { (a: A) => f(a); a })
```

So key to remember is `Option` since Scala 2.13 is an `IterableOnce` but not a full `Iterable`. `IterableOnce` is smaller compared to `Iterable`, so if a capability is needed from `Iterable` it is provided via implicit conversion as per [docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html#tapEach%5BU%5D(f:A=%3EU):C)

> This member is added by an implicit conversion from `Option[A]`
> to `Iterable[A]` performed by method `option2Iterable` in `scala.Option`.

that is

```
option2iterable(Option(5)).tapEach(_ => ())
```

hence the `Iterable[Int]` return type.

Also consider the following [note](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.5/src/library/scala/Option.scala#L124)

> Many of the methods in here are duplicative with those in the
> Traversable hierarchy, but they are duplicated for a reason: the
> implicit conversion tends to leave one with an Iterable in situations
> where one could have retained an Option.

so contributors would have to bake a specialised version in Option to preserve the type, or perhaps we could provide our own specialised extension implementation, something like

```
scala> implicit class OptionTapOps[A](v: Option[A]) {
     |   def tapEach[B](f: A => B): Option[A] = { v.foreach(f); v }
     | }
class OptionTapOps

scala> Option(5).tapEach(_ => ())
val res11: Option[Int] = Some(5)
```

Comment: Thanks, great explanation! I would like to contribute a specialised version of tapEach in Option to preserve the type. Do you have experience contributing? ... Should I just create a pull request, or should there first be a bug or something else the pull request refers to?

Comment: @Georg I asked on the scala contributors gitter channel, and they say to open the PR at https://github.com/scala/scala-library-next

Comment: https://github.com/scala/scala-library-next/pull/80